# Eclipse compatibility mode in IntelliJ IDEA - for Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, compatibility

I've read something about a so called "**Eclipse compatibility mode**" in IntelliJ IDEA.
Unfortunatelly I couldn't find any further informations about that mode, just that one link:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+in+Eclipse+Compatibility+Mode

I am working in a **team consisting of Eclipse-users** and I do not want to use eclipse.
Is the compatibility mode something I can consider, or do I need to stick to Eclipse?
Is this mode just for pure java-projects or is it usable for android development too?

How does it work and where can I find more informations about it?
Anything can help (Sorry for bad english).

**EDIT**:
I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community edition**

Comment: Btw, in addition to IDEA you also have Android Studio that is more tailored for Android development. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: @Patrick yea I used AS for a while now and I like it...but in AS it seems impossible to work in a Team (on the same Project), where everyone else is using Eclipse for Android (without annoying workarounds).

Comment: I'm an Intellij user amidst Eclipse users. We just use Maven and share the pom.

Comment: @matthelliwell previously I didn't use Maven...
Does the project structure of the Eclipse projects remain the same?
what is necessary for working the way you do?

Comment: Basically, you need to get your project building under Maven outside of Eclipse or IntelliJ. This can be a good thing to do in itself but isn't necessarily trivial. You then import the Maven project into Eclipse and IntelliJ. The project layout may change slightly as Maven expects a certain directory layout, src/main/java and src/test/java.